# Are .img files block-aligned like actual filesystems?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Filesystems like ext4 are block-aligned, meaning files are aligned to blocks of a predefined size, typically 4 KB in the case of ext4. If an `.img` file is created from such a filesystem, can I assume that the individual files are 4k aligned in the created `.img` file, just like they are in the real filesystem?

In other words, say we have two 1 KB files called `foo` and `bar`, which appear on the physical drive as below, with each [] representing 1 KB.

```
[foo][][][][bar][][][]
```

In this case, `foo` and `bar` are 4k aligned. Now, if we create an `.img` file for this filesystem, are the contents of `foo` and `bar` still 4k aligned from the start bit of the img file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define "an img file". *If* you mean a simple copy (e.g. from `cp /dev/sdx1 file.img`, `dd if=/dev/sdx1 of=file.img`, `cat /dev/dsx1 > file.img`, `pv …`, …) then you don't have to think about "an img file created from the filesystem". It's a copy of the filesystem, so *a* filesystem as well.

The only difference is the original filesystem exists (usually) on a block device, while the copy exists as a regular file you call "an img file". But it's the same sequence of bytes (until one of the filesystems is mounted and thus altered). You can mount the copy and use it.

So yes, every structure or alignment from the original (with respect to the beginning of the original block device) also exists in the copy (this time with respect to the beginning of the regular file).

Comment: In my case, I created an ext4 filesystem using mke2fs, then add files to it using e2fsdroid. Then I ended up with an img file that can be mounted.

Comment: @Dennis: Right, so it's an image created the same way as if done on a block device.  This answer still applies.  The fact that it can be mounted tells you that the data layout within the file is valid for the filesystem, and ext2/3/4 filesystems align their stuff in blocks.  (It doesn't just *choose* to do that based on detecting the logical sector size of the device it's creating on; I assume it stores "pointers" (e.g. from inode to actual data extents) on disk in a format that assumes the low N bits are zero, not actually storing those low bits to save space / make larger FSes possible)

Comment: @Dennis So the fragment "if an `.img` file is created from such a filesystem" does not really describe your case. Your `mke2fs` had to assume some block size anyway. If it was on a block device, the tool would check the physical sector size and adjust its default values if needed (see `man 8 mke2fs`, `-b` option). In a regular file there is no such thing as sectors, still some block size had to be used and it's probably some sane value. I'm not sure if the tool checks the block size of the filesystem holding the file. Anyway, internally in the filesystem blocks of some size are used for sure.

Comment: But would the byte boundaries in the file align with the byte boundaries on the disk? That's what I took the OP as asking.